# Dell Vostro 1720 - Screen won't display when started, but will display after being tapped a few times

Tags: laptop-repair, dell-vostro, tft

A friend of mine has a Dell Vostro 1720, and he says that when he switches it on the screen will be blank. It remains blank until he taps the back of the screen on both sides a few times. After this, the screen will come on and stay on for the rest of the day until it is switched off.

He has checked the connections on the motherboard etc and they seem to be fine. I have a feeling that it might be the actual TFT panel, but it doesn't seem to be a right diagnosis since the screen will then stay on the rest of the day.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tapping fixes the problem, then the problem is mechanical, probably a bad connection that fixes itself when the working temperature goes up.

If you cannot see anything obviously lose, and do not have the expertise to go after the problem, then either ask for help from a knowledgeable friend that has the right tools, or take the computer to a repair-shop.